# Decomposition of a cadlag and of local bounded variation function $Z:\mathbb{R}_+\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

Let $Z:\mathbb{R}_+\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be cadlag and of local bounded variation with $Z(0)=0$ and $V_Z(t)$ denotes the value of the total variation of $Z$ on $[0,t]$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}_+$. I want to show that there is a <s>unique</s> decomposition $Z=Z_1-Z_2$ of monotonically increasing and right-continuous functions $Z_1,Z_2:\mathbb{R}_+\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$, such that $Z_1(0)=0=Z_2(0)$ and $V_Z=Z_1+Z_2$, more precisely

$$Z_1=\frac{V_Z+Z}{2},\quad Z_2=\frac{V_Z+Z}{2}-Z.$$

I know that $V_Z-Z$ is monotonically increasing and right-continuous with $V_Z(0)-Z(0)=0$. Therefore it holds also for

$$Z_2=\frac{V_Z-Z}{2}$$

But I do not know how to show monotonicity and right-continuity for $Z_1$. Also I do not know how to show uniqueness. I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: To show monotinicity, note that if $t < s$, then
$$ V_Z[0,s] = V_Z[0,t] + V_Z[t,s] \geq V_Z[0,t] + |f(s)-f(t)|. $$

Comment: Thanks, so we get $V_Z[0,s]+Z(s)\ge V_Z[0,t]+Z(t)\ge V_Z[0,0]+Z(0)=0$, right-continuity is again clear, since Z is right-continuous.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that I wrote $f$ instead of $Z$ in my first comment, sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to MisterRiemann's comment one has

$$\forall\  0\le s\le t: V_Z[0,t]\ge V_Z[0,s]+Z(s)-Z(t)$$

which is equivalent to

$$\forall\  0\le s\le t: V_Z[0,t]+Z(t)\ge V_Z[0,s]+Z(s)$$

$Z_1(0)=0$ and right-continuity of $Z_1$ are obvious from definition of $V_Z$ and $Z$.

Suppose there exists another decomposition $X_1,X_2$ with the properties stated above, i.e. $$\exists\ t\in\mathbb{R}_+:X_1(t)>Z_1(t)$$

From $X_1(t)-X_2(t)=Z_1(t)-Z_2(t)$ follows $X_2(t)>Z_2(t)$ and we get
$$V_Z(t)=Z_1(t)+Z_2(t)<X_1(t)+X_2(t)=V_Z(t),$$ which is a contradicition. The other case $X_1(t)<Z_1(t)$ can be proven in an analogue way.